# Will memcached use bigger slabs for small values if no small slab is available?

Tags: memcached

Suppose I have a memcache with one page holding 96 bytes slabs, and one page holding 120 bytes slabs.

If the 96 bytes page is full and I try to insert data of size < 96 bytes, will it use a 120 bytes slab ? Or is it going to evict an element in the 96 bytes page to save the other page for elements where 96 < size < 121 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a free page available, it will turn this free page into a page with 96 bytes chunks.

If there are no free pages available, it will evict the LRU object in pages with 96 bytes chunks to store the new object.

If you'd like to hear in details about Memcached, I recommend [this PyCon talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/2578/cache-me-if-you-can-memcached-caching-patterns) or [this article](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/02/06/memcache-internals/).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Just to clarify, a "free page" is not a page with no element in it ; it's a page that was never used. So once your memcache has assigned a slab class to a page, it'll never change again (until reboot).

Comment: @Zonko yes, that is correct. On startup, memcached allocates one page per slab class, the rest are free pages. It then allocates free pages to slab classes as needed. If a page is devoid of objects, it is not returned to the free page pool.